# PostgreSQL: Using the LEAST() command after GROUP BY to achieve first transactions

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am working with a magento table like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| date      | email        | product_id | product_type | order_id | qty_ordered |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 2017/2/15 | x@y.com      | 18W1       | custom       | 12       | 1           |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 2017/2/15 | x@y.com      | 18W2       | simple       | 17       | 3           |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 2017/2/20 | z@abc.com    | 22Y34      | simple       | 119      | 1           |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 2017/2/20 | z@abc.com    | 22Y35      | custom       | 31       | 2           |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
```

I want to make a new view by grouping by email, and then taking the row with the LEAST of order_id only.

So my final table after doing this operation from above should look like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| date      | email        | product_id | product_type | order_id | qty_ordered |  
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 2017/2/15 | x@y.com      | 18W1       | custom       | 17       | 1           |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| 2017/2/15 | z@abc.com    | 18W2       | simple       |   31     | 3           |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+-------------+
```

I'm trying to use the following query (but it's not working):

```
SELECT * , (SELECT DISTINCT table.email, table.order_id,  
    LEAST (order_id) AS first_transaction_id
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    email)
FROM table;
```

Would really love any help with this, thank you!

Comment: Your final table example doesn't make sense. Is there a mistake in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (email) t.*
from t
order by email, order_id;
```

`distinct on` is a Postgres extension.  It takes one record for all combinations of keys in parentheses, based on the `order by` clause. In this case, it is one row per `email`, with the first one being the one with the smallest `order_id` (because of the `order by`).  The keys in the `select` also need to be the first keys in the `order by`.